# what is the time and space complexity of this FOR loop?

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity

- here alphabets array can be just ['a'] or ['a', 'c'] or all the
  alphabets -> unique entries, max can only be 26
- here words array can be from 1 to many records. no upper bound

  for(int i=0; i <alpahets.length; i++){ //let's say size is A
     for(int k=0; k < words.length; k++){ //let's say size is W
        // here we may exit from inner 'for' loop or outer 'for' loop with some conditions
     }
  }

My question is since alphabets char array max size is only 26 (min=1 ), is the time complexity O(26*W) which is O(W), or is it still O(A*W)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity should be O(A * W) because your actuall length is A. I don't quite sure that I'v understand from your question about the max length: 
is the length of the alphabets array might have change? - is there any function that would add letters to your alphabets array which might increase its length up to 26 or it depends on a user input? if does so the time complexity should be
 O(N * W) when N=26 --> the wors't case

Comment: Nathan, thanks for the response. No, the alphabet array WILL NOT change dynamically. What was set originally, will remain the same till the end, i.e. there will not be any change in both the arrays.

Comment: Ok, so the actual length (which are A, W) is what matters ( in time complexity terms, the computer have to deal with the actuall arrays). Thank for your endorsement!